# Overloaded virtual function warning

Tags: c++, clang, warnings

What should I do about this code which is now not compiling? Should I add `void funccall(const String e);`?

```
struct Base
{
     virtual void funccall(const String e = "");
};

struct Derived: public Base {
    using Base::funccall;
    void funccall();
    void funccall(char* e, int index);
};
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], and if you're getting compilation errors, also the full text of these errors. As is, your code will comple just fine.

Comment: Please post the error message or warning.

Comment: Voting to close, as without the error message this question is unanswerable.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My guess is that you have to define a pure virtual function

```
struct Base
{
     virtual void funccall(const String e = "")=0;
};
```

or define a body for this method

```
struct Base
{
     virtual void funccall(const String e = ""){};
};
```

Addition to the post:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>

class base
{
public:
    virtual void funccall(const std::string e = "") {}
};
class derived : public base
{

    void funccall() {};
    void funccall(char *e, int index) {};
};

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: in addition I d use classes not struct. Anyways I tried using std::string instead of String. you need to include <string>